# Electron with serialport native module

Tags: javascript, electron

Hello I am trying to use the serialport module in electron, but when running this tries to find the module anywhere the only place it does not look is in the node_modules folder, already run electron-rebuild and electron-builder install-app-deps but nothing .

```
Uncaught Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /home/myusername/my-projects/yuumi-cnc/build/bindings.node
 → /home/myusername/my-projects/yuumi-cnc/build/Debug/bindings.node
 → /home/myusername/my-projects/yuumi-cnc/build/Release/bindings.node
 → /home/myusername/my-projects/yuumi-cnc/out/Debug/bindings.node
 → /home/myusername/my-projects/yuumi-cnc/Debug/bindings.node
 → /home/myusername/my-projects/yuumi-cnc/out/Release/bindings.node
 → /home/myusername/my-projects/yuumi-cnc/Release/bindings.node
 → /home/myusername/my-projects/yuumi-cnc/build/default/bindings.node
 → /home/myusername/my-projects/yuumi-cnc/compiled/12.4.0/linux/x64/bindings.node
 → /home/myusername/my-projects/yuumi-cnc/addon-build/release/install-root/bindings.node
 → /home/myusername/my-projects/yuumi-cnc/addon-build/debug/install-root/bindings.node
 → /home/myusername/my-projects/yuumi-cnc/addon-build/default/install-root/bindings.node
 → /home/myusername/my-projects/yuumi-cnc/lib/binding/node-v73-linux-x64/bindings.node
    at bindings (bindings.js:126)
    at Object../node_modules/@serialport/bindings/lib/linux.js (linux.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:726)
    at fn (bootstrap:100)
    at Object../node_modules/@serialport/bindings/lib/index.js (index.js:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:726)
    at fn (bootstrap:100)
    at Object../node_modules/serialport/lib/index.js (index.js:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:726)
    at fn (bootstrap:100)

I have no idea how to solve this
```